# I want to achieve half border on right side of div as shown in image

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, border

I want to achive as shown below in comps image link.
[Comps Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMsw3.png)

My html structure is something like this

```
<div class="module-box carilion-proud-logo-section">
    <div class="left-section">
        <svg>Carilion Proud Logo svg</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="right-section">
        <a href="">Visit the hub</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS structure is something like this

```
.carilion-proud-logo-section {
  margin: 0 30px 30px 30px !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  .left-section {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 39px 0;
    background: url("../../../../../../assets/images/carilion-proud-blue.png")
      no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    clip-path: ellipse(100% 150% at 0% 50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .right-section {
    // padding: 39px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
}
```

The only issue is image should not have border and rest div element should have border

Answer (score 3):

the simpliest might be to use an inset shadow:
here is an example :

```css
div {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px gray;
  /* makeup for demo */
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
button {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/16/250/100"> <button>button</button></div>
```

The shadow draws a border but is hidden behind the image.